# Can webpy form work well with jinja2?

Tags: python, jinja2, web.py

As the cookbook of webpy and jinja2, I can use webpy's form or jinja2 well independently. However when I try to combining both in a template file like below, it does not work:

Template file:

```
$def with(form)
{% extends 'layout.html' %}
{% block maincontents %}
<h1>User</h1>
<form method="post">
    $:form.render()
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Part of python code:

```
render = render_jinja(
    'templates',
    encoding='utf-8',
)

class test:
    def POST(self):
        pass

    def GET(self):
        f = user_form()
        return render.test(f)
```

Comment: @Cat Plus Plus And it does not work

Comment: Oh, *right*, how silly of me.

Comment: @pat.inside, Cat Plus Plus as sarcastically saying that it'd really help if you can tell us exactly what happens when "it does not work". Do you get an exception, does it just not render as you expect, or something else? What else have you tried?

Answer (score 3):

`$:form.render()` is the Templetor rendering instruction, taken verbatim from the docs, I presume.

I believe you should use Jinja2 syntax, something like

```
<form method="post">
    {{ form.render() | safe }}
</form>
```

Disclaimer: I haven't actually tested the snippet above.